# Can I use ffmpeg to output JPEGs to a memory stream instead of a file?

Tags: ffmpeg, c#

I have a C# app. I have 100 JPEGs (for an example).

I can easily encode this into a video file.

When it has finished encoding on the client app I FTP upload to my server.

It would be 'neater' if I could not write the video file to a disc but instead write it to a memory stream (or array of bytes) and upload via web service perhaps?

I have checked out the ffmpeg documentation but as a C# developer I do not find it natural to understand the C examples.

I guess my first question is it possible, and if so can anyone post an example code in C#?  At the moment I am using the process class in C# to execute ffmpeg.

Comment: Note that FFmpeg command line questions go to Super User, while FFmpeg API programming questions belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you "stream" images to ffmpeg to construct a video, instead of saving them to disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t)

Comment: `ffmpeg` runs as a separate process, you cannot instantiate a stream directly hooking into or coming out of that. You can let `ffmpeg` pipe its output to `stdin` though, see the duplicate link and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16011/PipeStream-a-Memory-Efficient-and-Thread-Safe-Stre for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your process method is already good, just needs adjustments:

1. Set `StartupInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true` and `StartupInfo.UseShellExecute = false`.
2. Instead of an output file name, call ffmpeg with `pipe:`, which will make it write to the standard output. Also, since the format cannot be determined from the file name anymore, make sure you use the `-f <format>` switch as well.
3. Start the process.
4. Read from `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream` (`.BaseStream`, so the `StreamReader` that is `.StandardOutput` doesn't mess anything up) while the process is running into your memory stream.
5. Read anything still remaining buffered in `Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream`.
6. Profit.

I coded a [thumbnailer](https://github.com/nmaier/simpleDLNA/blob/060d602fd1606b0c18fea19eed6ed7f1ff12684c/thumbs/VideoThumbnailLoader.cs) a while back (BSD 2-clause), that has actual code that demonstrates this. Doesn't matter if it is an image or a video coming out of ffmpeg in the end.

Comment: AN interesting situation cropped up.  Have you ever had an occasion were the Process 'hangs' whilst doing this? I just have.  If I output it to a file on the hard drive no problem but outputting and capturing the base stream my code hangs...

Comment: Not really. But is it easy enough to deadlock something by not draining stdout (or stderr, if redirected) or not filling stdin (if redirected). See the remarks section of [`RedirectOutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Without the actual code you're using, it's hard to tell anything. Anyway, you should file a new question.