# Converting Incoming Byte Array File Type with FFMPEG - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG (FFlib .NET Library), is it possible to convert a stored byte array into another byte array, using the API rather than CLI, resulting in a different file type? I.e. .mov to .mp4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634749/can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-output-jpegs-to-a-memory-stream-instead-of-a-file

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for the reply.