# generate video from images without storing on disk ffmpeg .net

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I want to generate video file from images(memory stream bitmap or image object) without storing on disk with ffmpeg .net.
I found a link which is for python,but i don't know about python.
[Can you "stream" images to ffmpeg to construct a video, instead of saving them to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t)

Comment: possibly pass them through a named pipe to ffmpeg.exe?

Comment: can you please give me some sample.I am really stuck on it

Comment: in that python example, they're basically opening a pipe to "ffmpeg.exe" and instructing ffmpeg to read its input from "-" (which is its stdin).  You should be able to do something like that in C# as well, gl!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what interface to FFmpeg you're using (not familiar with C# interface), but the FFmpeg video encoding API expects the encoded frames from memory, not from disk. So when you call `avcodec_encode_video2` you pass the image in memory, not the disk file.

Comment: I'm not getting,what you want to say. Can you please give me sample which convert multiple image stream to single video without storing on disk .(.mov/.flv)

Comment: The question seems to concern streaming image data from a .NET based application to ffmpeg.exe using a named pipe rather than using the API to do a similar piece of functionality.