# Pipe PyQt Widget Images to ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyqt

I have a PyQt Window with widgets that change. I want to make a video of it. I found [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t) to be very useful, however it is does not seem to be possible to use subprocess PIPE as a target in QtGui.QPixmap's save-method. I have the feeling that I should use the native QtProcess for this kind of work, but I don't know how I can PIPE the images and I can't see the errors because I can't see the standard outpur/error either. What I want to do is something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import random

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win    = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)

#picture frame
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
canvas  = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
layout.addWidget(canvas,0,0)

# start button
def run():
    # set pen
    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
    size = canvas.size()
    
    # start seperate process
    process = QtCore.QProcess(app)
    process.start('ffmpeg',['-y', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-vcodec', 'mjpeg', '-r', '24',  '-i', '-', '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', '-qscale', '5', 'video.avi'])
    for i in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, size.width()-1)
        y = random.randint(1, size.height()-1)        
        scene.addLine(x,y,x,y, pen=pen)
        QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(win).save(process, "jpeg")
        
but_run = QtGui.QPushButton("Go!")
but_run.clicked.connect(run)
layout.addWidget(but_run,1,0)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out by myself. There are only a few commands to add:

`process.setProcessChannelMode(process.ForwardedChannels)` will redirect error and normal output of the child process to the main process. This allows you to see what ffmpeg does or not does.

---

**EDIT:** This is actually not needed.
`process.setOpenMode(process.WriteOnly)` this will Open the Input channel of the process.

---

I changed the file format to png because it looks better. JPG compression is not suited for large mono colored areas.

`process.closeWriteChannel()` Will Close the Input Channel. This is how ffmpeg knows there is no more data coming in.

And at last, call `process.terminate()` to close the process.

Here is the fully functioning code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import random

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win    = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)

#picture frame
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
canvas  = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
layout.addWidget(canvas,0,0)

# start button
def run():
    # set pen
    pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
    size = canvas.size()

    # start seperate process
    process = QtCore.QProcess(app)
    process.setProcessChannelMode(process.ForwardedChannels)
    #process.setOpenMode(process.WriteOnly)
    process.start('ffmpeg',['-y', '-vcodec', 'png', '-i', '-', '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', '-qscale', '5', '-r', '24', 'video.avi',"-loglevel", "debug"])
    for i in range(100):
        x = random.randint(1, size.width()-1)
        y = random.randint(1, size.height()-1)    
        scene.addLine(x,y,x,y, pen=pen)
        QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(win).save(process, "png")
    process.closeWriteChannel()
    process.terminate()
but_run = QtGui.QPushButton("Go!")
but_run.clicked.connect(run)
layout.addWidget(but_run,1,0)

win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Could you note what is now needed for Qt5? I changed QPixmap line to `QtGui.QWidget.grab(win).save(process, "png")`, but I don't see `video.avi` being written to disk.