# subprocess failing in GUI applications on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

Calling subprocess Popen, call, or check_output while running a python windows exe created with pyinstaller --noconsole results in an error with the following stack:

```
...
File "subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
File "subprocess.py", line 702, in __init__
File "subprocess.py", line 823, in _get_handles
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

Came across [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue3905) but no direct answer, so creating this post to hopefully make the solution easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid) by Alastair McCormack (thanks!!!!). Turns out the issue is that subprocess fails to properly resolve default stdin/out.

Copied for posterity:

---

Line 1117 in `subprocess.py` is:

```
p2cread = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
```

which made me suspect that service processes do not have a STDIN associated with them (TBC)

This troublesome code can be avoided by supplying a file or null device as the stdin argument to `popen`.

In **Python 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5**, you can simply pass `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`. E.g.

```
subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

In **Python 2.x**, you need to get a filehandler to null, then pass that to popen:

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=devnull)
```