# Executing subprocess in script executed as windows service

Tags: python, subprocess, pywin32

I tried to write a windows service using python, reference from http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python.

In SvcDoRun(), when I tried to use subprocess.check_output(), I get a exception, 'WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid'.

Is there a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python running as Windows Service: OSError: \[WinError 6\] The handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid)

Comment: I followed the link you specified, I could see all my process opening in background instead of foreground