# Subprocess run works from Python, but not when using R and Reticulate

Tags: python, r, subprocess, reticulate

I have a command saved in a text file that I wish to execute using `subprocess.run()` from R using the `reticulate` package.

I have a directory with three files:

- test_command.txt which contains the command `touch foo.txt`
- run_command.py:

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.check_output('bash test_command.txt')
print(os.path.isfile("foo.txt"))  # Check if the command was actually executed properly
```

- run_from_r.R:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("my_env")  # Same conda environment as used for python
source_python("run_command.py")
```

When I run run_command.py directly, foo.txt is created, and `True` is returned.

However, when I run from R using run_from_r.R, I get the following message:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Danie\miniconda3\envs\wildcats_summer_env\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Danie\miniconda3\envs\wildcats_summer_env\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Danie\miniconda3\envs\wildcats_summer_env\lib\subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Users\Danie\miniconda3\envs\wildcats_summer_env\lib\subprocess.py", line 1054, in _get_handles
    p2cread = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
```

`system("bash test_command.txt")` runs properly in R.

Any idea what this error message means, and how I can make the command run properly when running using `subprocess.check_output/run` and `reticulate`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it by using:

```
subprocess.run(['bash', 'test_command.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

From [Python running as Windows Service: OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid)