# pyinstaller error: OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pyinstaller

This File gets the wifi passwords using the terminal command `netsh wlan show profiles`
I used pyinstaller to create a few .exe before and they worked jut fine.

The Code:

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import re

command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile     : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = []

if len(profile_names) != 0:
    for name in profile_names:
        wifi_profile = {}
        profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        if re.search("Security key           : Absent", profile_info):
            continue
        else:
            wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
            profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
            password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)
            if password == None:
                wifi_profile["password"] = None
            else:
                wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]
            wifi_list.append(wifi_profile)

for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])

time.sleep(5)
print("No more WiFi Profiles Found")
time.sleep(3)
sys.exit()
```

This is the Error I get when Running the .exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetWiFiPassWord.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "subprocess.py", line 453, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1006, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error apparently is thrown, because of this:

> Line 1117 in subprocess.py is:  `p2cread = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)`
>
> The service processes do not have a STDIN associated with them (TBC).

This problem can be avoided by supplying a file or null device as the stdin argument to `popen`.

> In **Python 3.x**, you can simply pass `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.
> E.g.
>
> ```
> subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
> ```
>
> In **Python 2.x**, you need to get a filehandler to null, then pass
> that to popen:
>
> ```
> devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
> subprocess.Popen( args=[self.exec_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=devnull)
> ```

Reference: [OSError: (WinError 6) The handle is Invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid/40108817#40108817)

---

In your problem:

```py
subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL).stdout.decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem with pyinstaller:

```
PyInstaller: 4.5.1
Python: 3.9.6
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
```

thanks [Behdad Abdollahi Moghadam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14159253/behdad-abdollahi-moghadam). I've solved my problem by adding `stdin` and `stder` to `subprocess.check_output`

```
subprocess.check_output("C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx.exe", stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```