# Is there any way to create a video stream from image buffers(without saving to disk)using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

[Can you "stream" images to ffmpeg to construct a video, instead of saving them to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294919/can-you-stream-images-to-ffmpeg-to-construct-a-video-instead-of-saving-them-t)
I want something similar but in node js

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent for nodejs would be child_process https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html . The spawn call returns an object that has a stdin property (e.g. process.stdin), essentially the same as the answer you linked.